# Swift game lags when creating spritenodes

Tags: ios, swift

So I have recently uploaded a game to the app store and have been users reporting lags on older devices.
First of all, the game:
It is called "CURVE" (I am not sure if I am allowed to post its name here, but it would help you understand the problem).The idea of the game is that a ball moves up the screen and passes in gaps between walls. Also there are smaller balls that fall down from the main one, thus creating some sort of path.
Now, the lags. They occur in two main moments. First, when the path is created and second, when the player gets through the gaps.
When the player passes through the gaps, he collides with an invisible node. The collsion is noted, the score is updated. The node is then removed and the player proceeds.
I believe the lags occur when swift either creates a SpriteNode or deletes one. Any ideas as to how to deal with this problem?

Here is the code I use when spawning my obstacles - I think it is where the problem is

```
func createRocks() {

    rockHeight = (frame.height * (heightOfRocks))

    if gameState != .Dead {

    switch spawnCount {

    case 10:
        levelUp()

    case 20:
        levelUp()

    case 30:
        levelUp()

    case 40:
        levelUp()

    case 50:
        levelUp()

    case 60:
        levelUp()

    case 70:
        levelUp()

    case 80:
        levelUp()

    case 90:
        levelUp()

    case 100:
        levelUp()

    case 110:
        levelUp()

    case 120:
        levelUp()

    case 130:
        levelUp()

    case 140:
        levelUp()

    case 150:
        levelUp()

    default:
        break

    }
    }
    ++spawnCount






    let leftRock = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: (frame.width), height: (rockHeight)), cornerRadius: (cornerRad))
    leftRock.fillColor = themeColor
    leftRock.strokeColor = themeBorderColor
    leftRock.lineWidth = themeBorderWidth

    leftRock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: ((frame.width) + (themeBorderWidth)), height: ((rockHeight) + (themeBorderWidth))))



    leftRock.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



    let rightRock = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: (frame.width), height: (rockHeight)), cornerRadius: (cornerRad))
    rightRock.fillColor = themeColor
    rightRock.strokeColor = themeBorderColor
    rightRock.lineWidth = (themeBorderWidth)


    rightRock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: ((frame.width) + (themeBorderWidth)), height: ((rockHeight) + (themeBorderWidth))))
    rightRock.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


    leftRock.zPosition = CGFloat(10 + (21 * levelNumber))
    rightRock.zPosition = CGFloat(10 + (21 * levelNumber))


    // 2
    let rockCollision = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: (frame.width * 2), height: 32))

    rockCollision.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rockCollision.size)
    rockCollision.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    rockCollision.name = "scoreDetect"

    addChild(leftRock)
    addChild(rightRock)
    addChild(rockCollision)



    // 3

    let rockWidth = frame.width

    let yPosition = frame.height + leftRock.frame.height

    let rockDistance = frame.width * (gapWidth)

    let min = Int(((frame.width) * (wallWidth)) - (rockWidth / 2))
    let max = Int(((frame.width) * (1.00 - ((wallWidth)))) - rockDistance - (rockWidth / 2))


    let rand = min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min)))
    //GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: min, highestValue: max)

    let xPosition = CGFloat(rand)



    // 4
    leftRock.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    rightRock.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition + rockWidth + rockDistance, y: yPosition)


    rockCollision.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))

    rockCollision.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: yPosition + (rockCollision.size.height * 2))





    let endPosition = frame.height + (leftRock.frame.height * 2)



    let moveAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -endPosition, duration: timeOfRockMovement)
    let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    leftRock.runAction(moveSequence)
    rightRock.runAction(moveSequence)
    rockCollision.runAction(moveSequence)
}
func initRocks() {



    let create = SKAction.runBlock { [unowned self] in
        self.createRocks()
    }

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(rockSpawnWait)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([create, wait])
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

    runAction(repeatForever)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach sounds very similar to [a SpriteKit tutorial I wrote](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/36/overview), but I had no lag at all there. SpriteKit is awfully fast, but it's possible your exact conditions are causing problems. Things to check:

1) Are you using texture atlases? These are faster to load than separate images in your bundle.

2) If you're re-using images a lot, can you store them in an `SKTexture` then load your nodes from there?

3) Are there other things happening, such as sounds playing? The iOS Simulator frequently has a brief lag when it plays its first sound in a game.

4) Is the path that gets created very complicated?

Comment: Actually, I have used your lectures to start learning Swift=) By the way, thank you a lot. Your lectures are the most helping thing in the world=)
Now , to the question
1) I am not using atlases. I actually thought they were most useful when having several nodes moving together, while I have single nodes created all the time
2) I am not using any images. All my nodes are simple figures created by the game (circles and squares). I did so because I need to change their colors a lot through the game

Comment: 3) I read about this issue on your lectures so I just inserted a silent sound on the start of the game
4) No, it's just a lot of small circles falling down from the player, thus creating a "path"

Comment: I'm glad my tutorials are useful! As you've followed them, you might remember that in [project 20](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/20/overview) we used sprite colour blending to draw the same sprite with different colours – it's the most efficient way of doing it. If your sprites are the same apart from their colour, you might find that helps alleviate your performance issue.

Comment: what about the "path"? there, all of the nodes are identical, but it still causes lags. Also, as to what concernes the lag that happens when you score a point. It is not a lag per se, the player just moves down a couple pixels, then he gets back on the initial height (I presume, when the invisible node disappears).

Comment: It sounds like your path is so trivial it's unlikely to cause any performance problems, so I would rule that out.

Comment: to clarify, the player is always on the same height and only moves left or right, Every 0.3 seconds, a node is created at his position, which then moves to the bottom edge of the screen and gets removed. Thus, there is a nice sinusoide tracing the path of the player.

Comment: The thing is, I just don't have a lot happening in my app, and everything is so basic, that I have no idea as to what could cause the problem=)

Comment: the function used to create the path is similar to the one creating rocks in your tutorial

Comment: I'm afraid the only suggestion I have for you is to use Instruments and see where all your time is going. If you're not sure how, try [following project 30](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/30/overview). Remember to profile on a real device!

Comment: damn... all of the instruments you have shown in your lecture look fine to me - no red, no yellow anywhere... I believe now the lag is occuring when I am creating several SpriteNodes at a time... Wish I could at least understand, what to look at